# Are 'confusion' and 'confused' inappropriate tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

Are [confusion](/questions/tagged/confusion) and [confused](/questions/tagged/confused) inappropriate tags? Should they be removed?

Comment: Slang for ColdFusion, perhaps.

Comment: I'm not really sure if upvoting this Question says I agree they're appropriate ... or I agree they should be removed. I'm going by the title: appropriate

Comment: @pavium - better make it the negative then :)

Comment: Confusion matrix seems about the only valid use case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6281684/latex-constructing-a-confusion-matrix

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sounds like an utterly useless tag to me. There were only three so I burninated manually.

(They had nothing to do with ColdFusion, but even if they had I'd have changed them to something less confusing)

**Edit**: Turns out I was only looking at the *unanswered* tab. Full burnination of [confused](/questions/tagged/confused) and [confusing](/questions/tagged/confusing) tags now completed.

Comment: Hmm, there seems to be 23 questions tagged with [tag:confused] and 25 tagged with [tag:confusion]. Where did you get the number 3 from?

Comment: @Acorn - D'oh! Didn't realize I was only looking at the *unanswered* tab

Comment: Generally, we'll let moderators do tag burnination, as they have much more advanced tools for this. In particular, they can remove tags as a group without contributing to the edit history for the affected questions. This means that their edits don't "bump" a whole bunch of old, mostly-abandoned questions. And in certain cases (this may or may not be one), it's worth considering black-listing a tag rather than simply removing it.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than giving information on the question, those tags seem to give information about the OP, who is confused about something.
[confusion](/questions/tagged/confusion) could be used for a question about [a song](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_%28New_Order_song%29), but I don't think such question would be on-topic on *Stack Overflow*.